# Renderlayer is completely white and Im NOT on depth pass?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, render-passes, compositing-nodes

Ok, I dont know whats happening but I have a render layer that is just rendering white, and Im on Combined pass so thats not it. Settings:

[image]

The objects on that layer are special, but I dont see how that would affect things:

[image]

Whats wrong here?

Comment: Check that your UV image editor window isnt set to show alpha only?

Comment: Hey if I write that as an answer could you accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your UV image editor window isn't set to show alpha only.